# Limiting number of server methods in NGINX config file

Tags: nginx, redirect, phusion-passenger

I am trying to force a redirect for all non-www and non-https request to the https://www.example.com version of the site. It is a new site so there's no SEO implications of the redirects. I am trying to follow the documentation for NGINX found here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html but between that and the stuff certbot added, I am ending up a bit confused and concerned about the implications of multiple redirects.

Here is my current server config file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        # $scheme will get the http protocol
        # and 301 is best practice for tablet, phone, desktop and seo
        return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        server_name www.example.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /home/deploy/example_app/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

            listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
            listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
            include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
            ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 404;

}
```

Is this okay? Or am I more efficient to consolidate it somehow? The nginx docs state that doing so is *This is a wrong, cumbersome, and ineffective way.* but I feel unhappy with its current iteration.

If it matters, this is running as a Ruby on Rails site, hosted on Phusion Passenger + NGINX on a VPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just  delete the 3rd server {} section, and add www.example.com to the first server {} . So the server_name line on first becomes :

```
server_name example.com www.example.com;
```

And

```
return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
```

no reason for so many redirects.

And either list example.com in server_name in second server{} section, or add a new server{} section for port 443 with the necessary ssl config, which has server_name=example.com, then redirects to https://www.example.com

Comment: This is exactly the sort of refactoring I was looking for. Thank you, I really appreciate it.